# Sequence of piecewise constant functions converging to any $L^2$ function

Tags: analysis, approximation, lp-spaces

Let $\{P_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of [partitions of the interval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_an_interval) $[0,1]$ with a vanishing mesh. Additionally $H_i$ be the space of piecewise constant functions (step functions) with pieces defined by $P_i$.

> I want to prove that for all $x\in L^2([0,1])$ there exists a sequence
>   $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ of $x_i\in H_i$ such that
>   $\lim_{i\to\infty}\lVert x_i -x\rVert_{L^2} = 0$.

When the sequence of partitions is nested the proof is simple, I can prove it constructivelly. Roughly, let $\{\phi_j\}_{j=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of continuous such that $\phi_j\to x$, which exists due to denseness of continuous functions in $L^2$, and $\xi_{ij}\in H_i$ be the piecewise constant interpolation of $\phi_j$ at $P_i$. Then $\lim_{i\to\infty}\xi_{ij} =\chi_j$ and $x_i$ can be chosen as the $\xi_{kj}$ for $k,j\in\{1,\dotsc,i\}$ that is closer to $x$ making $\lVert x_i - x \rVert_{L^2}$ a monotonically decreasing sequence such that $x_i\to x$.

I am interested in the general case (partitions not necessarily nested), mostly out of curiosity to work out epiconvergence of discretized optimal control problems with general partition sequences. Polak ([1997](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-0663-7)), mentions that the requirement that the partitions be nested is mostly for convenience.
I struggled to prove this yesterday before giving up. It seems like an interesting exercise, however.

This question is similar to [Approximation in $L^2$ by piecewise constant functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/35323/90127).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fact 1.** *Lipschitz functions are dense in $L^2([0,1])$.*

*Proof.* Polynomials.

**Corollary.** For every $f\in L^2$, the distance $d_f(L):=\inf \{\|f-g\|_{L^2} : \text{$g$ is $L$-lipschitz}\}$ tends to zero as $L\to\infty$.

**Fact 2.** *For any Lipschitz function $f$ and any partition $P_i$ there is $f_i\in H_i$ such that $\|f_i-f\|_{L^2} \le L m_i$. Here $L$ is the Lipschitz constant of $f$ and $m_i$ is the mesh of $P_i$.*

*Proof*. For each subinterval, pick a point $x^*$ in it and define $f_i$ to be $f(x^*)$ on that subinterval. The Lipschitz property implies $\sup |f_i-f|\le Lm$. Conclusion follows.

To prove the result you want: Fix $f\in L^2$. Let  $L_i=1/\sqrt{m_i}$ where  $m_i$ is the mesh of $P_i$. Let $g_i$ be an $L_i$-Lipschitz function with $\|f-g_i\|_{L^2}\le 2d_f(L_i)$. Let $f_i$ be constructed from $g_i$ as in Fact 2. We have 
$$\|f-f_i\|_{L^2} \le \|f-g_i\|_{L^2} +\|g_i-f_i\|_{L^2} \le 2d_f(L_i) +  L_i m_i
= 2d_f(1/\sqrt{m_i}) +  \sqrt{m_i} $$
which tends to $0$ as $i\to\infty$.