# Piecewise constant approximation of stochastic processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

From the question [Approximation in $L^2$ by piecewise constant functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35323/approximation-in-l2-by-piecewise-constant-functions), I know I can approximate $L^2$ functions by piecewise constant functions. I wonder whether this claim also holds for stochastic processes.

Given a filtered probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{F}, \mathbb{P})$. Suppose there is a $\mathbb{R}$-valued $\mathbb{F}$-adapted stochastic process $X$, such that $\sup_{0\leq t \leq T} \mathbb{E} \vert X(t) \vert^2 < \infty$. Its piecewise constant approximation is defined by $X^h(t) = X(nh)$ for $t \in [nh, (n + 1)h)$, and $X^h(T) = X(T)$ with $h = \frac TN$ for some positive integer $N$. Do we have $X^h$ converge to $X$ in $L^2_{\mathbb{F}}(\Omega, \mathbb{R})$ as $h$ tends to $0$?

Comment: I think you might have to add some smoothness conditions on $X$ to it (e.g. càdlàg). The set of all points of the form $nT/N$ for every $n$ and $N$ is discrete and have Lebesgue measure 0, so on those points you can set the values of $X$ to 0 and basically whatever you want elsewhere for each $\omega \in \Omega$, so even if $X$ is uniformly bounded this doesn't offer enough to get some convergence unless mistaken.